# Actionscript code not executing but no compiler errors

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Below is the code I did for a basic button and menu interaction using flash tween and ease class for animation. Tested movie but no response and no compiler errors either except output panel says :

```
TypeError: Error #1123: Filter operator not supported on type builtin.as$0.MethodClosure.
    at CloudRail_fla::LaunchDeckcontrols_3/frame1()
```

where Cloudrail is my document name.

Here is the code :

```
switchbd_btn.addEventListener.(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ShowswitchBD);

var switchbdIN:Tween = new Tween (switchbd, "x", Strong.easeOut, 1089.05, 277.85, 1, true);
var switchbdOUT:Tween = new Tween (switchbd, "x", Strong.easeOut, 277.85, 1089.05, 1, true);

function ShowswitchBD(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (switchbd.currentFrame == 1)
    {
        gotoAndStop(2);
        switchbdIN.start();
}
    else {
        gotoAndStop(1);
        switchbdOUT.start();
    }
}`
```

please what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`switchbd_btn.addEventListener.(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ShowswitchBD);`

should be

`switchbd_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ShowswitchBD);`

Comment: If you're wondering what the difference is, there is a superfluous period in the original code after `addEventListener` - this is the cause of the stated error.

Comment: Yes, for sure that line is not correct. Not sure if it's the cause of the problem, but as inverse mentioned, you may have a typo there.

Comment: Thanks, it's sorted. Quite interesting to note the level of headache one dot  is capable of creating.